# Sequence File in Spark - Read And Write Custom

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

We had a data pipeline which was earlier built on Hadoop. But now we are trying to port some of our application to Spark.

In our data pipeline we had used sequence file as OP for each stage and which is passed to next stage.
So there are custom classes already written for Hadoop which implements Writable Interface for storing these data.

If I am trying to use it in Spark by creating the object of that class and save it as Sequence File I am getting errors like

Text/IntWritable or any other Writable class as not Serializable.
Is there any way to save the Sequence File in Spark using these custom classes.

The class is already present in Java and I don't want to modify those
Sample Example

```
public class Abc implements Writable,Serializable{
    private Text requestId;
    private Text requestType;

    //Constructor and other methods
    @Override
    public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
        requestId.write(out);
        requestType.write(out);
    }

    @Override
    public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
        requestId.readFields(in);
        requestType.readFields(in);
    }
}
```

Its giving an error as Text object is not Serializable.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make you custom class both `Writable` and `Serializable`.  E.g.

```
class MyText(var string: String) extends Writable with Serializable {

  def this() = this("Empty")

  override def write(out: DataOutput): Unit = {
    Text.writeString(out, string)
  }

  override def readFields(in: DataInput) : Unit = {
    string = Text.readString(in)
  }
}
```

If possible, I would move away from Sequence Files, and switch to Parquet, for example.  You can see issues with Sequence Files, especially with Scala, where on reads Sequence Files are not immutable and you can get the same value for all objects in a collect.  [See this JIRA ticket.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-993)

If you have a Java class which already implements `Writable` you could try creating a new class which inherits from that custom class and implements `Serializable`.  E.g.

```
class MyWritableAndSerializable extends MyCustomJavaWritable with Serializable {

    def this() = super.this()

}
```

Comment: I am able to write to sequence file using Scala Class but my Class is already present in Java and I don't want to modify it as there are some important custom codes in it.(Part of important flows). I have updated the question can you please help me onto this

Comment: I have updated my answer with a suggestion, note I haven't tested it.

Comment: "If possible, I would move away from Sequence Files, and switch to Parquet, for example. You can see issues with Sequence Files, especially with Scala, where on reads Sequence Files are not immutable and you can get the same value for all objects in a collect." Thank you Sir, I have been debugging this for a day now, and was just about to lose hope.